# How to identify, what is stalling the system in Linux?

Tags: linux, embedded, embedded-linux

I have an embedded system, when I do the user i/o operations, the system just stalls. It does the action after a long time. This system is quite complex and has many process running. My question is how can I identify what is making the system stall - it does nothing literally for 5 minutes. After 5 minutes, I see the outcome. I really don't know what is stalling the system. Any inputs on how to debug this issue. I have run the top on the system. However, it doesn't lead to any issue. See here, the jup_render is just taking 30% of CPU, which is not enough to stall the system. So, I am not sure whether top is useful here or  not.

~ # top

top - 12:01:05 up 21 min,  1 user,  load average: 1.49, 1.26, 0.87
Tasks: 116 total,   2 running, 114 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 44.4%us, 13.9%sy,  0.0%ni, 40.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  1.4%si,  0.0%st
Mem:    822572k total,   389640k used,   432932k free,     1980k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   227324k cached

```
 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND          
850 root      20   0  309m  32m  16m S   30  4.0   3:10.88 jup_render                                                                            
  870 root      20   0  221m  13m  10m S   27  1.7   2:28.78 jup_render                                                                            
  688 root      20   0 1156m 4092 3688 S   11  0.5   1:25.49 rxserver                                                                               
    9 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    2  0.0   0:06.81 ksoftirqd/1                                                                            
   16 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    1  0.0   0:06.87 ksoftirqd/3                                                                            
 9294 root      20   0  1904  616  508 R    1  0.1   0:00.10 top                                                                                    
  812 root      20   0  865m  85m  46m S    1 10.7   1:21.17 lippo_main                                                                               
   13 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    1  0.0   0:06.59 ksoftirqd/2                                                                            
  800 root      20   0  223m 8316 6268 S    1  1.0   0:08.30 rat-cadaemon                                                                        
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    1  0.0   0:05.94 ksoftirqd/0                                                                            
 1456 root      20   0 80060  10m 8208 S    1  1.2   0:04.82 jup_render                                                                            
 1330 root      20   0  202m  10m 8456 S    0  1.3   0:06.08 jup_render                                                                            
 8905 root      20   0  1868  556  424 S    0  0.1   0:02.91 dropbear                                                                               
 1561 root      20   0 80084  10m 8204 S    0  1.2   0:04.92 jup_render                                                                            
  753 root      20   0 61500 7376 6184 S    0  0.9   0:04.06 ale_app                                                                                
 1329 root      20   0 79908   9m 8208 S    0  1.2   0:04.77 jup_render                                                                            
  631 dbus      20   0  3248 1636  676 S    0  0.2   0:13.10 dbus-daemon                                                                            
 1654 root      20   0 80068  10m 8204 S    0  1.2   0:04.82 jup_render                                                                            
  760 root      20   0  116m  15m  12m S    0  1.9   0:10.19 jup_server                                                                            
    8 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0                                                                            
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                                               
    7 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/1                                                                            
  170 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kblockd                                                                                
    6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0                                                                            
  167 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 sync_supers                                                                            
  281 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 nfsiod
```

Comment: What type of I/O operation are you doing which triggers this?

Comment: Let me admit this this system is a STB. I did a channel zap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an embedded system that has many process running, there can be multitude of reasons. You may need to investigate in all perspective.

Check code for race conditions and deadlock.The kernel might be busy looping in a certain condition . There can be scenario where your application is waiting on a select call or the CPU resource is used up (This choice of CPU resource usage is ruled out based on the output of top command shared by you) or blocked on a read.

If you are performing a blocking I/O operations, the process shall get into wait queue and only move back to the execution path(ready queue) after the completion of the request. That is, it is moved out of the scheduler run queue and put with a special state. It shall be put back into the run queue only if they wake from the sleep or the resource waited for is made available.

Immediate step shall be to try out '**strace**'. It shall intercept/record system calls that are called by a process and also the signals that are received by a process. It will be able to show the order of events and all the return/resumption paths of calls. This can take you almost closer to the area of problem.

There are other many handy tools that can be tried based on your development environment/setup. Key tools are as below :

'**iotop**' - It shall provide you a table of current I/O usage by processes or threads on the system by monitoring the I/O usage information output by the kernel.

'**LTTng**' - Makes tracing of race conditions and interrupt cascades possible. It is the successor to LTT. It is a combination of kprobes, tracepoint and perf functionalities.

'**Ftrace**' - This is a Linux kernel internal tracer with which you can analyze/debug latency and performance related issues.

If your system is based on TI processor, the CCS(Trace analyzer) provides capability to perform non-intrusive debug and analysis of system activity. So, note that based on your setup, you may also need to use the relevant tool .

Came across few more ideas :
**magic SysRq key** is another option in linux. If the driver is stuck, the command `SysRq p` can take you to the exact routine that is causing the problem.

Profiling of data can tell where exactly the time is being spent by the kernel. There are couple of tools like Readprofile and Oprofile.  **Oprofile** can be enabled by configuring with CONFIG_PROFILING and CONFIG_OPROFILE. Another option is to rebuild the kernel by enabling the profiling option and reading the profile counters using **Readprofile** utility by booting up with `profile=2` via command line.

**mpstat** can give 'the percentage of time that the CPU or CPUs were idle during which the system had an outstanding disk I/O request' via 'iowait' argument.

Answer (score 0):

You said you run the `top` app. Did you find out which programme gets the biggest CPU time and how much is a percentage for it?

If you run the `top` you should see another screen in there, which you neither provided  nor mentioned a cpu load percentage (or other relevant info).

[image]

I advise you to include what you can find interesting/relevant or suspicious through `top`. If it was already done you should discover it in your question more distinctively because now it's not obvious what is the CPU maximum load.

Comment: I have edited my question now. I have put up more information now.